# Random change of rows of two matrices using indices

Tags: python-3.x

Any idea or clue about writing below problem code in python 3.6?

Imagine I have matrix A and B as below:
A = [1 2, 3 4, 5 6] with the dimension of 3*2
B = [1, 3, 5] with the dimension of 3*1

Now I want to change the rows randomly using indices.

for instance index 1 related to [1 2] from A and [1] from B, index 2 related to [3 4] from A and [3] from B,  index 3 related to [5 6] from A and [5] from B.

Imagine randomly I order the indices as 2, 3, 1, now my output will be: 
A=[3 4, 5 6, 1 2] 
B=[3, 5, 1]

Comment: Get a list of indices [0..n], randomise them and then loop through them accessing A and B on the current value of the loop?

Comment: Thanks  a lot I got my answer, as below: import numpy as np
A = [[1, 2],[3, 4], [5, 6]]
A = np.array(A)
B = [[1], [3], [5]]
B = np.array(B)
import random
def rand(n):
    l = list(range(n))
    random.shuffle(l)
    l = np.reshape(l, (n,1))
    return l
l = rand(3)
print(l)
AF = []
AFF = []
BF = []
BFF = []
for i in range (0, len(A)):
    AF = A[l[i]]
    AFF.extend(AF)
    BF = B[l[i]]
    BFF.extend(BF)
B = np.array(BFF)
A = np.array(AFF)
print(B)
print(A)

Comment: Please post your answer as an actual answer, with the code properly formatted (select the code and then click the little {} icon to format it) and then select it as an answer.  On a side note, mention things like numpy in your question. Also, look at Pandas. Glad you're sorted!

Comment: I am not familiar with how to format the answer, as soon I learn how to do so, I will put it there. Thanks a lot for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np 
A = [[1, 2],[3, 4], [5, 6]] 
A = np.array(A) 
B = [[1], [3], [5]] 
B = np.array(B) 
import random 
def rand(n): 
    l = list(range(n)) 
    random.shuffle(l) 
    l = np.reshape(l, (n,1)) return l l = rand(3) 
    print(l) 
AF = [] 
AFF = [] 
BF = [] 
BFF = [] 
for i in range (0, len(A)): 
    AF = A[l[i]] 
    AFF.extend(AF) 
    BF = B[l[i]] 
    BFF.extend(BF) 
    B = np.array(BFF) 
    A = np.array(AFF) 
print(B) 
print(A)
```